# Where can I ask about citing a legal statute?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a law I wish to cite in an article. I know the Act/Chapter/Section/Subsection/sub-subsection, etc. But, I don't know how to write this in a way that doesn't span 3 lines. What Exchange would be the appropriate place to ask such a question?

This is a State law, in the United States and the law relates to education within the state.

Comment: Depends on the kind of article you're writing. The conventions in a scientific paper and in a newspaper would be quite different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions about style conventions, and questions about technical, academic, scientific, business, and other types of writing are on-topic on [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com).  A question about how to cite legal sources would be just fine there.

Please describe any constraints you already know about for your situation -- e.g. if there's a particular style guide you follow, or the type of publication it'll have (conference paper, court proceedings, magazine article, etc), as this information can inform answers.